# Timing and clock skew problems in digital designs

Tags: digital-logic, clock

I am reading ["Rapid Prototyping of Digital Systems: SOPC Edition"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387726705), and on p.113 it contains the following statement:

> In VHDL, as in any digital logic designs, it is not good design practice to `AND` or gate other signals with the clock. Use a flip-flop with a clock enable instead to avoid timing and clock skew problems.

Could you explain what exactly are those "timing and clock skew problems", and give some contrasting examples of good and bad designs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the case where you have some data that you want to latch into a register under some particular conditions:

[image: simple flip-flop circuit]

Here you would assert the gate signal whenever you want to save the data from flip-flop D1 into flip-flop D2 (maybe the D2 is a read buffer or part of a shift register, and a read transaction was just detected). 
However, meanwhile the input data to D1 may be changing.

The clock signal to the D1 happens pretty much as soon as the clock generator produces a rising edge. D2, however, doesn't see the clock edge until sometime later, due to the propagation delay through the AND gate.

If D1's state has changed, then D2 might latch in the new data, rather than old data you expected from your RTL simulation. Worse, depending on the clock-to-Q delay of D1 , the AND gate delay, and the flip-flop hold time, D2's input may be in the middle of changing when it detects the clock signal rising edge, causing its output to go metastable.

If, instead, you use a flip-flop with a clock-enable input,

[image]

you won't have this problem. Assuming the flip-flops have zero hold time (typical within FPGA's), there's no extra delay for the clock reaching D2, and the two flip-flops will sense the clock edge at (darn near) the same time. Then D2 will always see the "old" data from D1 as your RTL simulation led you to expect, and won't have a problem with metastability.

Comment: (+1) Many thanks for the very clear explanation!

Comment: One approach I would think would be helpful in many cases, but which I've not seen discussed much, is having different latches triggered on opposite edges of the input clock.  Clock-enables are cleaner than clock gating, but for low-power systems, I would think that gating a clock would save more power than disabling the latches the clock feeds.  If the signal which gates a clock won't change anywhere near an edge of that clock, and if latches controlled by the gated clock will switch on the opposite clock edge from latches "before" or "after", are there any problems?

Comment: @supercat, within a chip (FPGA or ASIC) what your propose has at least two problems: 1. reduced amount of combinatorial logic that can be placed between two registers. 2. Imperfect duty cycle of the clock would further reduce the amount of delay you could tolerate in logic between registers.

Comment: @supercat, on the other hand, for between-chip interfaces, what you suggest isn't uncommon. SPI normally works this way, for example. Difference is that between chips, the digital logic designer can't control the relative skew between the clock signal and data signals.

Comment: I can see that input clock duty cycle could sometimes be an issue.  On the other hand, for parts of a design that aren't running near maximum device speed, I would think that certain aspects of device verification could be easier, since one wouldn't have to worry about hold times anywhere--just setup times.  Also, another issue I was wondering about: if a register's clock is fed by an "or" gate within an FPGA, and one input of that gate is high, could a change on the other cause a glitch on the output sufficient to trigger the register?

Comment: You might be right, but the situation is probably that the synthesis vendors put their R&D into making very fast designs work, and slow designs just come along for the ride. So if they have a system (zero-hold-time FF's) that lets us design at both 100 MHz and 500 MHz, developing that is more important to them than making things "even easier" at 100 MHz only.

Comment: I would imagine that for fast FPGAs which have substantial static currents, allowing to minimize clock-related currents wouldn't be a consideration, but some vendors are pushing energy-efficient devices.  I would think that in an energy-efficient device, one would want to shut off clocks to unused parts of a circuit.  To be sure, the right approach might be to include controlled-skew gated clock buffers (specifying that provided all registers which are clocked from gated clock buffers that are themselves driven from a common clock will operate together). Not sure what such features exist, tho.

Comment: @supercat, I think in "efficient" FPGAs, and probably also ASICs, they do allow shutting off clock to certain parts of the chip, but not on a flop-by-flop basis, more like for whole regions of the chip as a group.

Comment: @ThePhoton: In many cases, it's useful not just to shut off clocks but vary the speed of clocks to different sections based on requirements.  In some cases, it may be useful to have some microcontroller peripherals like timers running at a constant clock rate while the CPU switches between speeds that are faster and speeds that are slower.  I would think that when interfacing e.g. a timer to a CPU, when both are divided down from the same clock source, clocking the timer on the input edge opposite the CPU would be the easiest way to handle both the 'faster' and 'slower' cases interchangeably.

Comment: @supercat, I'm not totally following your use case, but there's no reason you couldn't do that in an FPGA, for example, if it gave the best timing margin.

Answer (score 2):

The various signals and clock will have to pass through several devices, to achieve the desired logic function. These devices will have slightly different propagation delays, which will affect the timing of the signals, and will delay the clock slightly, skewing the edges relative to the other signals. At low clock speeds these effects are unlikely to cause problems, but they could result in a high-performance system failing to operate properly.

I've got the Quartus II edition of that book, BTW.

Comment: There is the possibility of hold time violations, which can ruin your day at any clock frequency. The more skew in your clock, the bigger your nightmares (at least in SoC's)